# boostrap lists inline issues w/ fiddle and attempted code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, jsfiddle

New to coding have a boostrap issue in regards to list-inline and not displaying function.

I tried this in sublime text and jsfiddle, but neither provide me with the desired end result.

Note: 2 cdnjs already added to the fiddle

Visit: http://jsfiddle.net/thomasmccabe44/fqce10na/

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
  <li>Item Three</li>
</ul>  

<ul style="display: inline;">
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
  <li>Item Three</li>
</ul>  

<hr>
```

Attempt 2

Item One

Item Two

Item Three

Attempt 3

Item One

Item Two

Item Three

I expected: Item One Item Two Item Three

Actual results:
Item One
Item Two
Item Three

or

Item One 
Item Two
Item Three

All returned with bullet points.

Comment: I think you should understand css, and how it works with HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootrstrap 4, your `ul` should have the `list-inline` class, and your `li`s should have the `list-inline-item` class:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item One</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item Two</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item Three</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help Ismael!

Comment: You're welcome @Thomas, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider upvoting it and accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Cheers!